# OSC-address in MAX/MSP

Tags: python, arduino, xbee, osc, max-msp-jitter

Can anyone help me with a problem routing OSC messages?  I'm using Python, MAX/MSP with OSC to communicate between Arduino Xbees.

I hope there's someone out there!

Comment: Maybe you can provide some details of what you've been able to do so far, and what you're currently having problems with?

Comment: You need to ask a specific question. Then we can help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On python, install pyosc. There are examples file within the package.

On maxmsp, use udpsend or udpreceive. Remember to match the IP and port number.

Without specific details, it is hard to answer your question in a more precise way. But hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at the [XBee Internet Gateway](http://code.google.com/p/xig/)?  It's Python-based, runs on Mac/Windows/Linux and communicates over an XBee module with other XBee modules.

According to section C of the [User Documentation](http://code.google.com/p/xig/wiki/UserDocumentation):

> Contributed by Axel Roest, the Open Sound Control session allows for
>   XBees to multicast Open Sound Control events to a set of targets
>   running on remote Open Sound Control severs. Configuration of Open
>   Sound Control servers is specified within the XIG configuration file's
>   "osc_targets" section (see the CONFIGURATION section, below).